# Taking Inputs in an unsized Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I take inputs in an unsized Two-Dimesional array. I just can't figure out how to create an array as such. I even tried ArrayList. But the Second-Dimendional array needs to be sized. But I can't determine the size for the array.

Comment: Of which language are you talking? Tag your question properly. Also you should show us some code so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean to set the size of the two dimensional array at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ArrayList, couldn't you just do something like this?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then to take input, just make another ArrayList, add your inputs in there and add that ArrayList to this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do if I didn't know the size of my multidimensional array at compile time but wanted the user to provide that information.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        System.out.println("Enter number of rows");

        int row = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter number of columns");

        int column = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());

        int[][] myArray = new int[row][column];

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < column; x++) {
            myArray[i][x] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine()); //
        }
    }
        //This second for-loop will print the two dimensional array
       for(int i = 0; i <row; i++) {
           for(int x = 0; x<column; x++) {
               System.out.print(myArray[i][x] + " ");
           }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```